# Coregraphics Private API usage leads to app rejection?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I am using `Core graphics` Private API [this](https://github.com/robbertkl/ResolutionMenu/blob/master/Resolution%20Menu/DisplayModeMenuItem.m) will this lead to app rejection
As i enabled sandbox and it is working will this make any trouble for me?

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: You can always try. Not all private APIs are tracked. Sandbox doesn't affect use of private APIs.

Comment: @MarekH apple will approve if i use this ?

Comment: Private api in apple frameworks means only apple needs to use the functions. They do not represent stable macOS calls. The app will probably be automatically screened out and rejected.

Comment: @zack no one knows as we don't know which private APIs are checked. Make 100% sure your app won't crash if the API is no longer present/renamed in macos

Comment: No one can tell you what Apple will do. Guessing the future behavior of a corporation is not the business of Stack Overflow. Take your own chances.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assume that if you use a private API, your app will be rejected. Apple's intent is to not allow any app in the App Store to use private APIs.

You could always contact Apple DTS and chat with them about your need and see if that leads towards anything useful to you in terms of getting a public work around, but I would expect that to end with a request to file a feature request.